# MEF with extra DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, mef

I have an Outlook plugin created that uses MEF to load extensions.  The extensions are all created as C# class libraries. When the Outlook plugin starts, it copies all the plugin DLLs from a network directory to the local computer and then loads them via MEF.

For one of them, I'm using the MySql.Data.dll library.  That dll is copied to the same directory where I place the DLL's which MEF loads in, but that one isn't working.  The end user gets an exception saying it can't find that MySql dll.

What's the trick to placing extra DLLs that are needed by a class library included via an MEF import?

Comment: What kind of catalogs are you using? Try adding some sample code and additional error information.

Comment: I'm using an AggregateCatalog(), and I loop through the DLL's in a folder passing them into an AssemblyCatalog().  The error is just "Could not load file or assembly, 'MySql.Data, Version.....'

Comment: Try using fuslogvw.exe to diagnose the assembly-loading error. It could be a dependency of MySql.Data that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used MEF in a project but I have had to roll my own plug-in architecture on a couple of occassions. Something you can try is hooking in to the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. I don't know how useful the example is on that page but you could examine the assembly name in the event args and attempt to load that assembly from the same folder you are loading the plug-ins from.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.  I took the assembly given, ran it though Assembly.LoadFrom() and then returned the result and now things work great.